# Google Analytics Referral Exclude Regex Partial Domain Name

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics, analytics

I am attempting to filter out some of the nasty analytics referral traffic. It doesn't touch my site, so htaccess is out.
I have to specifically go into Google to create a filter.  I have a few setup already, but am looking to try something new that will hopefully make my exclusion list a bit easier to manage.
I want to block any referral traffic coming from a domain that has seo, traffic, monitize, etc. in it.  This would stop about 90% of the referral traffic and would keep excluding sites.
What I currently use is this:

```
(seomonitizer|trafficseo|seotraffic|trafficmonitizer)\.(com|org|net|рф|eu|co)
```

It removes each site one by one, but when a new site hits, I have to add it to the list.

I'm not sure what the regex capabilities and limitations are of the Analytics filters, but possibly this may be the foundation, I'm just not sure what goes into the middle.

```
((?=())\.(?=()))
```

Thanks

Comment: GA uses RE2 engine, it does not support look-aheads (`(?=...)`).

Comment: Actually, what is the question?

Comment: Have you researched other methods first, as mentioned in this article: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will have to TO check and add each one of them to your list as they are appearing in your account. To answer your question I use as in the following example:

```
.*((darodar|priceg|buttons\-for(\-your)?\-website|makemoneyonline|blackhatworth|hulfingtonpost|o\-o\-6\-o\-o|(social|(simple|free|floating)\-share)\-buttons)\.com|econom\.co|ilovevitaly(\.co(m)?)|(ilovevitaly(\.ru))|(humanorightswatch|guardlink)\.org).*
```

I like to use .co(m)? instead of .com for example

Remember To avoid having ghost referrals currently there are 3 methods.

1) The first one (the one you are using) would be to create a filter that will blacklist all the bad traffic, but there is a limit for the amount of character you can use, so you might end up creating multiple similar filters to cover all the nasty analytics referral traffic. Here is a link with a [complete list of bad bots](https://github.com/raulreyes/referrer-spam-blacklist/blob/master/spammers.txt).

2) the second method is to check the box "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" in your Google Analytics Account >Property >View

[image]

3) Create a hostname Filter following [this article steps](http://www.annielytics.com/blog/analytics/how-to-add-a-hostname-filter-in-ga/).

Comment: Bot filtering has been on for a while, filtering is our main goto.  We just add them as they showup.  I was hoping to exclude any website that mentions the keywords "seo", "monitize", "traffic", etc.  This would exclude 99% of the referral spam.